# How to get project name from linked additional sources in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

When I create new project, there're files that I have to add to project by click on link additional sources like below
[image]

And now I want to create a plugin that reads name of project that the active file is in the project additional sources
How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you want to do. You can use `IWorkspaceRoot` `findContainersForLocationURI` or `findFilesForLocationURI` to go from an absolute file path to an `IContainer` or `IFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever needed this, I found project like below:

```
IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
    IEditorPart editorPart = part.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput) editorPart.getEditorInput();
    IFile file = input.getFile();
    IProject activeProject = file.getProject();
    return activeProject.getName();
```